webRTC android : Audio is not flowing when call is answered during locked state using notifications
we are using webRTC for peer to peer calling, foreground calling is working fine two way audio flowing between these peers, However we have implemented accepting call using notifications, so whenever call is accepted during the locked state of the device, i can hear other device audio but local audio is not reaching the recipient,
i checked the local audio source and local audio track is this is LIVE and audio source object is also created.
what could be the issue ?
I have added wake lock while accepting the call, but it seems not working with wakelocks.
